# Calculating pixel in array

Tags: python, arrays, image, matrix

I'm working with binary PBM format. When I read it, I have an array with integers, where integers are ordinals of bytes. Each integer in array is transformed to list of 0 and 1 integers as binary representation, then I inverse this list. Pixel grid starts from 0:0, so position of the first pixel is [0:0].

I need to get pixel color if x >= 8. If x < 8, everything works great. Code for getting pixel color.

```
  def getpixel(self, x, y):
    '''PNMReader.getpixel(x, y) -> int

    Get pixel at coordinates [x:y] and return it as integer.'''
    if not isinstance(x, int) or not isinstance(y, int):
      raise(TypeError('both x and y must be integers'))
    if x < -1 or y < -1:
      raise(ValueError('both x and y are interpreted as in slice notation'))
    if x > (self.width-1):
      raise(ValueError('x cannot be equal or greater than width'))
    if y > (self.height-1):
      raise(ValueError('x cannot be equal or greater than height'))
    width, height = self.width, self.height
    x = (x, width-1)[x == -1]
    y = [y, height-1][y == -1]
    p = (y *height) +x
    width, height = self.width, self.height
    pixels = self._array_
    q = (8, width)[width -8 < 0]
    if x >= q:
      while x % q:
        y += 1
        x -= 1
    from pprint import pprint
    color = bitarray(pixels[y])[::-1][:q][x]
    print(color)
```

`bitarray` which you can see here is my defined function for getting bits for integer as list; `self._array_` is a sequence of integers (which are just ordinals for bytes which were read from PBM).

I need to fix this function for getting pixel color if x >= 8. I can't understand how to calculate offset for x and y in such situations.

Only fast-working answers are accepted. I don't want joining all bits as 1-dimensional array, since it can be too slow if image is big (e.g. it can be 3000x5000 pixels).

I know that I could use some modules like `imagemagick` or `freeimage`, etc., but I can use only standart library (no additional modules). I need pure Python solution without bindings or non-default modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `self._array_` is an array of integers, each representing one byte of raster image data from the original image, then you can extract the bit you want using ordinary bit-manipulation techniques. Here's a detailed explanation (as requested in comments):

1. We need the width of each row in bytes. This is the width in pixels divided by 8, except that the PBM format pads each row with up to 7 dummy pixels to make each row an exact number of bytes. So we need to divide the width by 8 and round *up*, which can be done using integer arithmetic like this:

   ```py
   row_width = (width + 7) // 8
   ```
2. Then we need to find the byte containing the pixel we want. PBM raster data is laid out in row-major order, so the pixel at `(x, y)` is in this byte:

   ```py
   pixel_byte = self._array_[y * row_width + x // 8]
   ```
3. You can extract bit number `b` (numbering from the right, with least significant bit numbered 0) from the integer `i` using the operation `(i >> b) & 1` (right-shift by `b` bits and mask off the least significant bit). But PBM lays out its pixels in [*big-endian order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), with the first pixel being in the most significant bit in the byte. So the bit we want is bit number `7 - x % 8`:

   ```
   (pixel_byte >> (7 - x % 8)) & 1
   ```

That should solve your immediate problem. But it looks to me as though your code is very complex for what you are trying to do. Some comments:

1. It's pointless calling `isinstance` and raising a `TypeError` yourself, because this will happen anyway when you try to do integer operations on the arguments.
2. `x > (self.width-1)` would be better written as `x >= self.width`.
3. Python's slice notation allows any negative integer, not just `-1`. For example:

   ```
   >>> range(10)[-7:-4]
   [3, 4, 5]
   ```
4. You compute a number `p` but you don't use it.
5. You import the function `pprint` and then don't call it.

I would write something like this:

```py
import re

class Pbm(object):
    """
    Load a Binary Portable Bitmap (PBM) files and provide access to
    its pixels.  See <http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html>
    """
    _pbm_re = re.compile(r'''
       (P4)                     # 1. Magic number
       (?:\s+|\#.*\n)*          # Whitespace or comments
       ([0-9]+)                 # 2. Width of image in pixels
       (?:\s+|\#.*\n)*          # Whitespace or comments
       ([0-9]+)                 # 3. Height of image in pixels
       (?:\#.*\n)*              # Possible comments
       \s                       # A single whitespace character
       ([\000-\377]*)           # 4. Raster image data
    ''', re.X)

    def __init__(self, f):
        m = self._pbm_re.match(f.read())
        if not m:
            raise IOError("Can't parse PBM file.")
        self.width = int(m.group(2))             # Width in pixels
        self.height = int(m.group(3))            # Height in pixels
        self.row = (self.width + 7) // 8         # Width in bytes
        self.raster = m.group(4)
        if len(self.raster) != self.height * self.row:
            raise IOError("Size of raster is {} but width x height = {}."
                          .format(len(self.raster), self.height * self.row))

    def getpixel(self, x, y):
        # Negative coordinates are treated as offsets from the end,
        # like Python's slice indexes.
        if x < 0: x += self.width
        if y < 0: y += self.height
        if x < 0 or x >= self.width or y < 0 or y >= self.height:
            raise ValueError("Coords ({},{}) are out of range (0,0)-({},{})."
                             .format(x, y, self.width - 1, self.height - 1))
        return (ord(self.raster[y * self.row + x // 8]) >> (7 - x % 8)) & 1
```

Comment: You've probably missed my notice: bitarray which you can see here is my defined function for getting bits for integer as list. It is not bitarray from `bitarray` package.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a critique of all of their code, so I suspect you're just showing off.

Comment: What's wrong with showing off? If the OP doesn't like the rest of my answer, they can ignore it. And so can you!

Comment: No-no, everything is OK, I like to listen to constructive critics. :-) Thank you very much, I accept it!

Comment: @GarethRees: It would be useful for some other people who may find this page if you describe what happens in `self._array_[y * row_width + x // 8] >> (7 - x % 8)) & 1`. Bitwise operations are hard to understand for novice. However, I don't insist.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, coordinate check can be smaller if you use `any([x < 0, x >= self.width, y < 0, y >= self.height])`. :-)